# When dettol turns white, what does it indicate

Tags: disinfection, chemical

Sometimes when I bathe or clean wounds with dettol, It upon contact turns white almost instantaneously. Does it mean there's some kind of microbes or something ?. If so what causes it it turn white ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dettol upon contact with `H2O` turns milky like white.

When H2O is added to the dettol liquid its oil droplets become suspended in the water droplets, creating something called an Emulsion.

It is that state of emulsion that causes the colour to change with its response to light.

Comment: Does this emulsion sting you upon contact ??

Comment: The addition of water particles will not likely affect the feeling of the application. Usually adding water to any solution makes a dilution. Dilutions' are invariably weaker than the concentrate/original solution. Dependent on the application and chemical of course.